# I want to check its on same origin or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my web page(mydomain.com/xyz.php) open in  in both same & different origin.
when it's open in same origin I update html of top window using jquery code which is inside xyz.php.

```
window.top.$("#idxzy").html(img_block);
```

all things is okay in same origin but when my web page open in different origin that time this line create error :
xyz.php?product_id=XXXX Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "htt p s://www.mydomain.com/" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

```
window.top.$("#idxzy").html(img_block);
```

so I want to add condition here something like below but I don't know what should I use in if

```
if(same_origin){
    window.top.$("#idxzy").html(img_block);
}
```

also if I put console.log() for window.top.location.
it's display something like below
(same origin)

[image]

(not same origin)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Window.postMessage() to communicate between the iframe and the parent windows.

[Here is the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage)

[Here you can find more info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy/3076648#3076648)

You can also try catch to prevent the console error

```
try {
  if (location.hostname == "mydomain.com") {
     window.top.$("#idxzy").html(img_block);
   }
}
catch(err) {
  // Make sure you catch the exception thrown because is blocked by cross domain reference => then do 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `location.hostname`:

```
if (location.hostname == "mydomain.com") {
    window.top.$("#idxzy").html(img_block);
}
```